# Bootstrap Multicolumn Form-horizontal Styling only one one col-

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I have an order form on my website, using the `form-horizontal` class provided in bootstrap. The form has a left and right section in the form of two columns. The left col is formatting great as it should with `form-horizontal` but the right col isn't unfortunately. Any help to get it looking right would be greatly appreciated!

You can find it live here: http://www.bannermastering.co.uk/order.html

**Form Code**

```
<form id="orderform" name="orderform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="ordermailer.php">
  <div class="row">

  <!-- """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""" -->
  <!-- CLIENT INFO [Left side of order form] -->
  <!-- ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, -->

  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 form-top-border form-bg client-info">

    <h2 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Client Info</h2>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtartistname" class="col-sm-3 control-label ">Artist Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input id="txtartistname" name="txtartistname"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Artist / Group / Band Name"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtclientname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Your Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input id="txtclientname" name="txtclientname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtemail" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input id="txtemail" name="txtemail" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="example@domain.com"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtnotes" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Track Listing & Notes</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <textarea id="txtnotes" name="txtnotes" class="form-control" rows="4"
          placeholder="Please enter Track Names and Additional Information e.g Mastering Preferences" value=""></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""" -->
    <!-- ORDER DETAILS [right side of order form] -->
    <!-- ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, -->

  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 form-top-border order-details form-bg">
    <h2 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Order Details</h2>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txttrackquantity" class="col-sm-9 control-label label-padding bottom-border-dark">Number of Tracks to Master</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3 margin5">
          <input id="txttrackquantity" name="txttrackquantity" type="text" onkeyup="calculatetotal()" class="form-control" placeholder="0" maxlength="2" data-fv-notempty />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtstemquantity" class="col-sm-9 control-label label-padding bottom-border-dark">How many of these need Stem Mastering?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3 margin5">
          <input id="txtstemquantity" name="txtstemquantity" type="text" onkeyup="calculatetotal()" class="form-control" placeholder="0" maxlength="2"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtdualquantity" class="col-sm-9 control-label label-padding bottom-border-dark">How many require a Dual Master?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3 margin5">
          <input id="txtdualquantity" name="txtdualquantity" type="text" onkeyup="calculatetotal()" class="form-control" placeholder="0" maxlength="2"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="chkDDP" class="col-sm-9 control-label label-padding bottom-border-dark">DDP Format Master</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2 margin5">
          <input id="chkDDP" name="chkDDP" type="checkbox" class="faChkSqr" onclick="calculatetotal()"/><br>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rdoloudness" class="col-sm-4 control-label bring-left small-top-padding">Desired Loudness</label>
        <br>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input id="engineersdiscretion" name="rdoloudness" value="Engineers Discretion" type="radio" checked/>Engineers Discretion
          </label>

          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input id="dynamic" name="rdoloudness" value="Dynamic" type="radio"/>Dynamic
          </label>

          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input id="balanced" name="rdoloudness" value="Balanced" type="radio"/>Balanced
          </label>

          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input id="loud" name="rdoloudness" value="Loud" type="radio"/>Loud
          </label>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- / Loudness Radios -->

  </div> <!-- /COL ORDER DETAILS -->

<!-- PRICING ROW -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 credit-card-logos">

    <div class="col-xs-3 margin40">
      <h4 class="pull-right"><strong>Pay With</strong></h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <!-- PayPal Logo -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr><td align="center"></td></tr><tr><td align="center"><a href="https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/paypal-popup" title="How PayPal Works" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/paypal-popup','WIPaypal','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=1060, height=700'); return false;"><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/mktg/Logo/AM_mc_vs_ms_ae_UK.png" border="0" alt="PayPal Acceptance Mark"></a></td></tr></table><!-- PayPal Logo -->
    </div> <!-- /col-md-10 -->

  </div><!-- End Credit card logos left panel -->

    <!-- PRICE PANEL -->
    <div class="col-md-5 form-top-border form-bg pricing-panel">

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2 id="txttotalprice" name="txttotalprice">Total £0.00</h2>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cbocurrency" class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1 control-label" style="padding-top: 5px">Currency</label>

            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1" style="padding-top: 5px">
              <select id="cbocurrency" name="cbocurrency" onchange="calculatetotal()">
                <option value="£">GBP</option>
                <option value="$">USD</option>
                <option value="€">EUR</option>
                <option value="$">AUD</option>
              </select>
            </div>

          </div><!-- /form-group -->
        </div><!-- /row -->

      </div><!-- /col-sm-5 -->

      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Do NOT use name="submit" or id="submit" for the Submit button -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn order-button">Confirm & Pay</button>
        </div><!-- /form-group -->
      </div><!--/col-sm-4 --> 

      <!-- Hidden inputs to hold data for the PHP script that emails the order -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" id="hidtotalprice" name="hidtotalprice" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="hidcurrencycode" name="hidcurrencycode" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="hidcurrencysymbol" name="hidcurrencysymbol" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="hidurlend" name="hidurlend" value="">
      </div>


    </div><!-- End Price /col-md-5 -->
</div> <!-- End Row -->
```

Comment: looks great from my end mate! what seems to be the issue? are you by chance using internet explorer/

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate it!
I'm using chrome mostly (others for cross-browser testing), the problem was the CSS formatting from form-horizantal was only applying to the left column.

Ron down there just got me thinking of a way to do it by overriding it with targeted CSS like this though:

'.order-details{
  min-height:330px;
  margin-top: 15px !important;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.order-details .control-label{
  text-align: left;
}'

Here's how it's meant to be if you want to see!
http://bannermastering.co.uk/order.html

Thanks for the help dude!

Comment: Oops sorry i'm a stack newb and tried using ' to format the code:

`.order-details{
  min-height:330px;
  margin-top: 15px !important;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.order-details .control-label{
  text-align: left;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear for me what would look RIGHT for you, but from what I see, you might want to move the underlines on the right a bit by adding `padding-left:30px` for example to the right div:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 form-top-border order-details form-bg" style="padding-left: 30px;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man, you got me thinking of a way to do it. not using a style but by targeting it through CSS like this:

`.order-details{
  min-height:330px;
  margin-top: 15px !important;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.order-details .control-label{
  text-align: left;
}`

Here's how i wanted it to look: bannermastering.co.uk/order.html

You're awesome! Have a great day dude

Comment: looks nice. Thank you too. If my answer really did the job, you can mark it as the accepted one. I will appreciate it